# Is Snoke really the size that he is in the movie?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Snoke is HUGE in the movie.

[image]

Is he really that way?

Answer (score 2):

### No, the Snoke we see is merely a hologram.

[image]

He is actually [seven feet tall](http://makingstarwars.net/2015/12/people-magazine-confirms-snokes-height-and-weight-from-star-wars-the-force-awakens/).